# No export named vpc-xxxxxx-vpc-id found. Rollback requested by user

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cloud, terraform, aws-cloudformation

I am quite new to AWS and I am trying to launch a security group from and cloud formation: I have this in my parameters

```
  NetworkStackName:
   Description: "Network Stack Name which created connectivity resources (subnets, routing, etc)."
   Type: String
   Default: vpc-xxxx
```

And it is being referenced in my resources as follows

```
Resources:

  JUMPsgID:
     Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
     Properties:
       VpcId:
         Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${NetworkStackName}:vpc-id"
```

when I try to lauch the template, I get this error

```
AWS::CloudFormation::Stack ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS No export named vpc-xxx:vpc-id found. Rollback requested by user.
```

I am sure it has something to do with this line Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${NetworkStackName}:vpc-id" but I am not sure how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

`NetworkStackName` is **not** the VPC ID. It should be the name of CloudFormation (CFN) stack which creates the VPC.

So check in the CFN, which is the name of the stack containing the VPC of interest. The use it as a default value in `NetworkStackName` parameter, or just pass it as such.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so I looked for the CFN for the VPC and its title XX-AWS-VPC and I used it as default yet I get this error still : No export named XX-AWS-VPC:vpc-id found. Rollback requested by user. @Marcin

Comment: @Theonestar Without full templates, no one will be able to provide more detailed answer. Does `XX-AWS-VPC` actually has such export? Maybe it does not, maybe it has different name? Only you know what these templates do.

Comment: @ this is what I got at the output of the CFN stack: Outputs:
  VPC:
    Description: A reference to the created VPC
    Value: !Ref VPC
  DeployVersionOutput:
    Description: Deploy Version of Cloudfoundation
    Value: !Ref DeployVersion

Comment: did you able to solve this issue? I'm facing the same issue right now.